# design a slide in beamer

Tags: beamer

How can I do those circles with the little pictures like this in my slide with beamer please??
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tikz package to draw a circle around your picture. Just use `\usepackage{tikz}`

For example, executing the following section:

```tex
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Circle around picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, draw=green!60, fill=green!10, very thick, minimum size=7mm}]
\node[roundnode]{\includegraphics{h8UFB}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

will give you the result below.
You can edit the style to achieve the look you want
[image: Picture example]